# Tizen Studio install error SIGNATURE_INVALID_CERT_TIME error 76

Tags: tizen, tizen-studio

When I install my application to Gear S2 (Commercial Device), SIGNATURE_INVALID_CERT_TIME error 76 has occurred.

I already use the Samsung certificate and I was using it well without problems until two weeks ago, but suddenly I had a problem.

I tried to find information about this error, but I could not find it.

Maybe I will create a new certificate and use it, but if you know the solution, let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the time of your development machine and your Gear is same. If not, then sync it and restart the IDE. 
Another reason could be, this certificate is not created for your current device. It was created for another S2/S3 or any other Tizen device. But now you are trying to install apps in the current device with previously created certificate(created for another device). 
Create certificate for your device if you have not created one for it.

Comment: The time on the laptop and the equipment were all the same. After restart the IDE, I tried but still failed.

Comment: Finally, I made a new distributor certificate of Samsung. It work well as I expected but I still wonder what SIGNATURE_INVALID_CERT_TIME  is.

Comment: @ Iqbal hossain Thank you for a answer. But I have only one device, only one laptop and only one Gear.

Comment: Did you create any certificate before ?  And then your reset your Gear. Then you are trying to install apps from PC using previous certificate ?