# Tizen Studio SIGNATURE_INVALID_CERT_TIME error 76 (Gear Fit2)

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-gear-fit

I'm trying to install an application in a Samsung Gear Fit2 using Tizen Studio 1.2
But every time I try to do so, I get the following error:

```
[Initializing the launch environment...]
    RDS: On
    Target information: SM-R360
    Application information: Id(PSOUXHWdyQ.TAUBasic), Package Name(PSOUXHWdyQ), Project Name(TAUBasic)
[Transferring the package...]
    Transferred the package: wgt stream -> /opt/usr/apps/tmp/TAUBasic.wgt
[Installing the package...]
path is /opt/usr/apps/tmp/TAUBasic.wgt
start process (install)
....
error : 76

end process (fail)
processing result : SIGNATURE_INVALID_CERT_TIME [76] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [1664]ms
cmd_ret:76
    An exception occurred
(Installing the package... > Fail)
An exception occurred
Unexpected stop progress...
(4.998 sec)
```

I have searched everywhere and followed the steps on the links below:

[Tizen Studio install error SIGNATURE_INVALID_CERT_TIME error 76](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44264194/tizen-studio-install-error-signature-invalid-cert-time-error-76)

https://developer.tizen.org/forums/general-support/gear-fit2-problem-signature_invalid_cert_time#comment-25819

https://developer.tizen.org/sites/default/files/documentation/1_tizen_studio_windows.pdf

But none of them have solved this problem.

Notes:

1. Both my development machine and smartwatch are on the same network.
2. Both devices date/time are synced
3. I'm using a Samsung certificate with a matching DUID from the device i'm trying to connect to.

Does anyone know what i'm missing?

Comment: Use Static IP and ensure closeness between connecting devices. You may give a light reset of your device. Recreate your certs also. Hope will work.

Comment: Thanks @Yasinshihab for your suggestion, but I unable to this in my current environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to install an app to the device.
It was a pretty long shot, but it worked!

I simply setup the device with a samsung device, and that's it!
I was using the smartwatch without connecting to a smartphone because we are developing a standalone app.

I guess it has something to do with the automatic date/time (timezone?) syncing between the smartwatch and smartphone. Not really sure.

Anyway, it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the directory where your author and distributors certificates are stored, and print them out using openssl:

```
openssl x509 -text -noout <author.crt
```

You'll see two cert's fields: "Not Before" and "Not After". It defines a time frame when certificate is valid.

```
     Not Before: Jun 24 16:24:11 2018 GMT
     Not After : Jun 24 16:24:11 2019 GMT
```

If the timer on your watch is out of sync and the date/time are not within this interval, the certificate validation will fail on the target device (watch).

That's why syncing the watch with its phone will resolve CERT_TIME (76) error.